# How do I undo Date.parse?

Tags: javascript, date

I convert a date to a number by running

```
Date.parse(doc.createdAt);
```

sO i GET THIS:

```
1576699528000
```

which probably turns it into a string as its getting passed from the server to the front end and then back to the server

How do I turn it back into a date object?

Comment: well I get a number of seconds. then i pass it to the front end and then pass it back and need to convert it back

Comment: this question was incorrectly closed

Comment: How do the duplicates not answer your question? You want to know how to turn a time value into a Date, they answer that (with 29 different answers to choose from, which include those given here).

Answer (score 2):

Just use constructor of `Date`:

```
let mls = Date.parse('Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00 GMT');
let date = new Date(mls );
```

An example

```js
let mls = Date.parse('Wed, 09 Aug 1995 00:00:00 GMT');
let date = new Date(mls);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: OMG. I have been going in circles on this for hours. Somehow your answer was the only one which clicked.... Specifically, if you type  `let date = Date(mls);` then it will return the time now (ie useless), but if you type  `let data = new Date(mls);`  then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Date.prototype.setTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) if you have a date object to shift over or just pass it to the constructor, ex. `new Date(num)`